# How much memory is the InProc Session State using on my ASP.net Server?

Tags: asp.net, session, memory, windows-server-2008, inproc

Is there any way to tell how much memory the InProc Session state is using for an ASP.net site at any one time? IIS7, ASP.net 3.5, Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668989/profile-memory-usage-of-session-state-asp-net