# C#: Bypass non-serializable properties when going about serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net

I follow the code snippet to calculate Session size.

[Profile Memory Usage of Session State ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668989/profile-memory-usage-of-session-state-asp-net)

My problem is some properties of objects **aren't marked as Serializable** so I cannot apply the solution.

Can I just **bypass** non-serializable properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, that isn't reliable *anyway* - the size of the session *in memory as objects* is not the same as the size of the objects *serialized* - and note that the choice of serialization is actually up to the session implementation you have selected.

When using `BinaryFormatter`, no: there is no way of automatically skipping non-serializable fields, unless you do a *lot* of work with" serialization surrogates". You could just edit the objects that you are storing? Or store simple (pre-serialized) data such as xml, json, `byte[]` etc.